# HTML - appendChild() in document itself (body)

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

From W3S, regarding what's a node: "*The document itself is a document node*"   ( [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) ). The `appendChild()` method is said to work like this: `node1.appendChild(node2)`. If I am understanding nodes correct, shouldn't I be able to append something into the document body? I have tried `document.appendChild(...)` and `window.appendChild(...)`, it didn't work. Right now I have to create a sort of frame and then append into that ( See example snippet ).

How can I append a `node` into the document as a whole? Instead of, as in the example below, append into a new `div`?

```js
function append(){
  box = document.createElement("div");
  box.style.backgroundColor = "#F00";
  box.style.width = "50px"; 
  box.style.height = "50px"; 
  document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(box); 
}
```

```html
<div id="frame" style="position:absolute; top:90px; width:100px; height:100px;border-style:solid; border-width:2px; border-color:#000;"></div>

<input type=button value="Append" onClick="append()">
```

Comment: What would it mean to append something to the "document as a whole"? I mean, there are two top-level things that would make sense to append to (head, body).

Comment: Trying to append a div to the document would result in invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of appending it to the document, you will need to append it to the body.

The issue with appending it to the document, is that only one element can be on the document at a time, and it is the body element currently.

```js
function append(){
  box = document.createElement("div");
  box.style.backgroundColor = "#F00";
  box.style.width = "50px"; 
  box.style.height = "50px"; 
  document.body.appendChild(box); 
}
```

```html
<div id="frame" style="position:absolute; top:50px; width:100px; height:100px;border-style:solid; border-width:2px; border-color:#000;"></div>

<input type=button value="Append" onClick="append()">
```

Comment: Simple as that, thanks! Have never seen the use of `body` before, but this is just what I was looking for!

Comment: Great! If you don't want the margin on the body use `margin:0;` in your CSS.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake That's because in general you'd never append to the body IRL.